# How to find in which way the data is inserted into a specific table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How to know in which way data is inserted into a particular table in SQL Server? Like through a stored procedure or views or jobs?

Comment: You can't, unless you stored that information at the time.

Comment: You can crawl through FN_DBLOG output to get which user inserted data, this might give a clue if it's a jobs or stored procedure (see applicationName / login etc). But better question is, why do you need this info?

Comment: You can set up an extended event session to capture queries touching a specific object name and log the sql_statements.

Comment: What do you mean by "through views"?

Comment: @Limonka - views can be updatable